# Play a video using gtk+

Tags: user-interface, video, gtk, mp4

Do you have any suggestion about playing videos using GTK+?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Playing Videos on GTK+ and other GTK Bindings you have a lot of options.

> **Option: Use A Third-Party Library**

1- Try using [ogmrip-gtk](http://ogmrip.sourceforge.net/en/manual.html) , A set of Gtk Interface, which allows you to use the open-source OGMRip library as a Gtk-Widget.

2- You may use another library, [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). Also can be used easily with Gtk.

3- You may use LibVLC - gtk. A GTK wrapper for LibVLC (ever used the VLC Media Player?). Personally , I like this a lot.

> **Option: Using Code from Open-Source Software**

1- The Banshee media player is open-source and although it uses Gtk#, you may have no trouble converting the code to GTK+.

2- See the MPlayer or Totem Player Source Code. (or any other for that matter, here is a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aGTK_media_players) )

> **Option: Use A Process**

1- I've heard the MPlayer Command Line is pretty simple. Here's a guide. http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/commandline.html

With GTK+ there are always a lot of new and innovative  (not to mention open-source) ways to do stuff. So always keep looking for better ways. I am personally a great fan of the GTK+ toolkit and have found that there is nothing you *cannot* do with it.

Answer (score 5):

[GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/) integrates well with GTK+.