# Opening a video file and play in C language

Tags: c, file, network-programming

I am creating a server/ client program in which client would request a video from server. Once it starts receiving the video packet, i am creating a video file and write into it.

My main question is after writing some frames, i have to open the video file and it has to play the video.
1) how to play a video file using C?
2) Is it possible to write on the same file and play the same file simultaneously??

Comment: How in the world do you expect to be playing a video on a server?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII From the description the OP clearly wants to play the video on the client. The role of the server is to ... serve the video to the client, which writes it to a file and plays it.

Comment: " Is it possible to write on the same file and play the same file simultaneously?" -- Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Hi Jim Balter thanks. can you please help me out in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C alone does not provide this functionality. You need to leverage an additional multimedia oriented library such as gstreamer and display it using a framework suitable to the environment you use, for example gtk under Linux be fine. Or use an external program and call it to play the video.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305736/play-a-video-using-gtk) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Adrian I am using GCC compiler in Ubuntu 12.04.i may have to use a VLC player to play that file. Can you please give some more details.

Comment: The feature you need is executing programs, in the manuals this will be under the keywords `system` for a basic approach. If you want to control the playback (pause,play), then research whether yyou can control VLC from stdin, if so, then consider `popen` and `execv` solutions; although what I think would be best for you is to use dbus to communicate with vlc. In which case you would either use a dbus to c binding or prepare shell scripts calling the dbus command, and calling those scripts with `system` from your program.